# Determine if DropDownlist Selection is in Bold Font

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I am writing an asp.net application that uses a dropdownlist to display various options. Depending on the user's authorization, some options are not allowed to be selected.
 The options that are restricted appear in bold font. 
How can I determine if the user has selected one of the bold-font options? I know this is a weird way of doing it, but it's how the app owner wants it done.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you post your drop down list code please?

Comment: If I were you, instead of parsing whether or not the option is in Bold font, I'd have some other property that determines whether an option "is restricted", and also determines whether the option is in bold font

Answer (score 1):

You could try interrogating the attributes of DropDownList.SelectedItem to see if the selected item is restricted.  How are you setting it the font property will determine how you can interrogate the selected item.

The only other way to do it is to re-run the logic to make the determination on the selected value, or store the indexes of the bolded items in a hidden field or viewstate property, or something like that.